# Unexpected module 'MdAutocompleteModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I'm getting this error in my angular 4 project after installing angular material

> unexpected module 'MdAutocompleteModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

that's my app.module.ts

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
// New imports to update based on AngularFire2 version 4
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

// import material
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  FullscreenOverlayContainer,
  MdAutocompleteModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdButtonToggleModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdCheckboxModule,
  MdChipsModule,
  MdCoreModule,
  MdTableModule,
  MdDatepickerModule,
  MdDialogModule,
  MdExpansionModule,
  MdGridListModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdListModule,
  MdMenuModule,
  MdNativeDateModule,
  MdPaginatorModule,
  MdProgressBarModule,
  MdProgressSpinnerModule,
  MdRadioModule,
  MdRippleModule,
  MdSelectModule,
  MdSidenavModule,
  MdSliderModule,
  MdSlideToggleModule,
  MdSnackBarModule,
  MdSortModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdTooltipModule,
  OverlayContainer,
  StyleModule
} from '@angular/material';



export const MaterialModules = [
    MdAutocompleteModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdButtonToggleModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdChipsModule,
    MdTableModule,
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    MdExpansionModule,
    MdGridListModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdListModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdCoreModule,
    MdPaginatorModule,
    MdProgressBarModule,
    MdProgressSpinnerModule,
    MdRadioModule,
    MdRippleModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdSidenavModule,
    MdSlideToggleModule,
    MdSliderModule,
    MdSnackBarModule,
    MdSortModule,
    MdTabsModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
    StyleModule
  ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MaterialModules
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,  // imports firebase/database, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth only needed for auth features
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CdkTableModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: you are not importing your `MdAutocompleteModule` into `AppModule`

Comment: I imported,I just edited my post

Comment: It is in declaration.

Comment: yes and I still facing in error

Comment: Add `... MaterialModule` in the import block

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are not importing that module

```
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ////////////////////removed///////////////////////
  ],
  imports: [
    ...MaterialModules, ////////////added here
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,  // imports firebase/database, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth only needed for auth features
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CdkTableModule
  ],
```